# Sending data in Chunks using single HTTP Post connection

Tags: http, go, post, chunks

I receive the contents of a file from a data source in chunks. As and when I receive the chunk I want to send the chunk data to a service using http POST request. And by keeping alive the same http POST connection used for sending the first chunk I want to send the remaining chunks of data.

I came up with the following code snippet to implement something similar.

**Server-Side**

```
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    buf := make([]byte, 256)
    var n int
    for {
        n, err := req.Body.Read(buf)
        if n == 0 && err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf(string(buf[:n]))
    }
    fmt.Printf(string(buf[:n]))
    fmt.Printf("Transfer Complete")
}
```

**Client-Side**

```
type alphaReader struct {
    reader io.Reader
}

func newAlphaReader(reader io.Reader) *alphaReader {
    return &alphaReader{reader: reader}
}

func (a *alphaReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := a.reader.Read(p)
    return n, err
}

func (a *alphaReader) Reset(str string) {
    a.reader = strings.NewReader(str)
}

func (a *alphaReader) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {

    tr := http.DefaultTransport
    alphareader := newAlphaReader(strings.NewReader("First Chunk"))

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
        Timeout:   0,
    }
    req := &http.Request{
        Method: "POST",
        URL: &url.URL{
            Scheme: "http",
            Host:   "localhost:8080",
            Path:   "/upload",
        },
        ProtoMajor:    1,
        ProtoMinor:    1,
        ContentLength: -1,
        Body:          alphareader,
    }
    fmt.Printf("Doing request\n")
    _, err := client.Do(req)

    alphareader.Reset("Second Chunk")
    fmt.Printf("Done request. Err: %v\n", err)
}
```

Here I want that when I do  **alphareader.Reset("Second Chunk")**, the string **"Second Chunk"** should be sent using the POST connection made earlier. But that is not happening. The connection gets closed after sending the **First Chunk** of data. Also I have not written the **Close()** method properly which I'm not sure how to implement.

I'm newbie to golang and any suggestions would be greatly helpful regarding the same.

Answer (score 3):

A *strings.Reader returns io.EOF after the initial string has been read and your wrapper does nothing to change that, so it cannot be reused. You're looking for [io.Pipe](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) to turn the request body into an io.Writer.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://localhost:8080/upload", pr)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }

    go func() {
        defer pw.Close()

        if _, err := io.WriteString(pw, "first chunk"); err != nil {
            _ = err // TODO: handle error
        }

        if _, err := io.WriteString(pw, "second chunk"); err != nil {
            _ = err // TODO: handle error
        }
    }()

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error
    }
    res.Body.Close()
}
```

Also, don't initialize the request using a struct literal. Use one of the constructors instead. In your code you're not setting the Host and Header fields, for instance.

Comment: Here we are sending both the strings "first chunk" and "second chunk" in single POST call, But I want to send the strings one after another but by using single post call. Basically I wish to connect the client and server using some reader and send the data in streams. Any way to implement that

Comment: I don't follow. You were asking how to send those chunks in a single request. Note that you can make the second write call whenever you want, as long as you don't close the write end of the pipe. The pipe is the connection you want.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. Using the pipes, by putting the post request inside a go routine and later writing to the pipe using pipewriter I'm able to send data in chunks one by one to the server using single post call.